# How to add the authentication tokens in the angular $http call

Tags: angularjs

How to add the authentication tokens in the angular `$http` call.

Planning to implement the identity and access management solution in later stage and like to make a provision to add the authentication token in the `$http`.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how your API expects that information to be sent!?
Normally you would need to add a `Authorization` header like this:

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = /* MY TOKEN */;
```

Comment: Ok Thanks. Is there any free tool which generates tokens and used for testing purpose